# Error in reading HDF5 using h5py

Tags: python, numpy, hdf5, h5py

I have saved my dataset in this form as mentioned in the following image (HDF5 format). So I have different groups i.e. 4, 2, 40 etc. and for each group I have 2 datasets `Annotation` and `Features`. I have save them successfully using code but I am unable to load them back.

Strange thing is the error occurs only when I try to read `Annotation`. And reading works fine when I try to read `Features`.

I am using the following code:

```
dataSet = np.array([])
annotation = np.array([])
hdf5Object = readHDF5File('abc.hdf5','r')
w = 2
myGroup = hdf5Object[str(w)]

dataSet = np.array(myGroup['Features'])
annotation = np.array(myGroup['Annotation'])
```

Please enlighten me here as I am struggling a lot for this for a while now. Thanks.

[image: View of HDF5 generated using ViTables 2.1]

**EDIT 1**

I am getting the following error when I read `Annotation`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xyz.py", line 76, in getAllData
    annotation = np.array(myGroup['Annotation'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/h5py/_hl/group.py", line 153, in __getitem__
    oid = h5o.open(self.id, self._e(name), lapl=self._lapl)
  File "h5o.pyx", line 173, in h5py.h5o.open (h5py/h5o.c:3403)
KeyError: "unable to open object (Symbol table: Can't open object)"
```

**EDIT 2**

So the hdf5 file was formed in 2 steps, in 1st step `Features` were calculated as follows:

```
features = <numpy array of thousand rows and 100 columns contains only floating numbers>
w = 2
f = h5py.File('abc.hdf5', 'a')
myGroup = f[str(w)]
myGroup.create_dataset('Features', data=features)
```

For different `w` file was appended and features were calculated at different times.

For annotation, same kind of procedure is used. `Annotation` contains only floating points as well.

**EDIT 3**

In the following image is content of data in `Annotation` and `Features` of one `w`. Left window is `Annotation` and right one is `Features`.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example that creates and loads such a file, so people can reproduce the error without access to your data? Thanks.

Comment: As far as I know, h5py does not support all features of hdf5 – could it be that your annotations use some more advanced feature? Could you supply an example file?

Comment: Please see edited post.

Comment: Can you open other files in h5py? Have you tried running the test suite (`h5py.tests.run_tests()`)?

Comment: @ali_m yes I am able to open other file by same code, it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just figured out that the way I was trying to access dataset was using `string` and somehow while saving dataset name it was saved under `unicode` or `utf-8`. So when I convert my dataset name to utf-8 it works fine.

**How I figured out its datatype**

```
    myGroup = hdf5Object[str(w)]
    childsIter = myGroup.iterkeys()
    for child in childsIter:
        print type(child)
```

This gave me the clue that the data type of my key of dataset is unicode and not just string. So I converted my string to unicode as follows:

```
key = unicode('Annotation', "utf-8")
dS = np.array(myGroup[key])
```

or

```
myGroup = hdf5Object[str(w)]
childsIter = myGroup.iterkeys()
for child in childsIter:
    dS = np.array(myGroup[child])
```